# Zend 2 Individual Access Control with Database

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, acl

I understand the concept of RBAC in ZF2, even with the ACL defined in config-files. But now I want to make some of my application modules available to individual users. E.g. user "foo@bar.com" may use modules A and C, user "bar@foo.net" has A and B available and so on. I can realize this in a MySQL database, but how could I do this in ZF2? I got an ACLService class with an "isAllowed" function where roles are compared, is this the right place to introduce some database?

Answer (score 0):

*In a few words a solution could be:*

You introduce a `user_role` table and a `role_privileges` table.
In your `user_role` table you link `user_id`, `email` or `username` (a unique user identifier) to a `role`.

In your `role_privileges` table you link the `role` to one or more `privileges` (in your case a `module`, but it could also be a controller name or a route or whatever you want to manage).

You could also skip the `role_privileges` table and define the privileges in a config. That is decision is up to you...

*If you don't want to write all the code then there are several ZF2 modules available that make this possible.*

Comment: So you mean roles like "moduleA_allowed" and every user is assigned to multiple roles?

Comment: @GiacomoVoß Yes, but you can also make it less abstract, let's say moduleA is an module for managing something then you can make role `manager` or if the module deals with administration you name the role `administrator`.

Comment: Take also a look at the ZF2 module [`BjyAuthorize`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize). [Here is also a link to a presentation](http://de.slideshare.net/stefanovalle/instant-acls-with-zend-framework-2) about `Acl` with that module to get an idea about how it works and what the possibilities are.